# Update Authenticated User in Supabase

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-flutter

I am updating user's email using the `.update({"email": newEmail})` method.
It is sending me the confirmation email only on the new email as I disabled secure email change in Supabase settings. But how will I know in the app that the user has clicked the link in the email?

I am using flutter for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup deep links in order to send the user back to your app after clicking the confirmation link:

You can follow the following guide to see how you can setup deep links in your Flutter app.

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/native-mobile-deep-linking?platform=flutter